# How was end-of-file stored on a Commodore 1541 disk?

Tags: commodore, floppy-drive, file-system

On a VIC-20 or C-64, you could open a sequential file on a 1541, write exactly N bytes (say, 47 bytes) to it, then close it. Then you could open the same file for reading and start reading byte by byte (with `GET#`, for instance). After reading the 47th byte, you would get a special status (reserved variable `ST` = 64 in BASIC) to tell you the end of file had been reached.

But by my recollection (and [this site](http://ist.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eschepers/formats.html)), the 1541 directory entry only contained a number of blocks, and the only metadata in each block was a track/sector pointer to the next block of the file. I don't see a precise byte count anywhere. And, as far as I know, all byte values (00 through FF) were allowed as content in the file, so no code could be used as an end-of-file marker either. So how did DOS "know" that it had reached the end of file at byte 47? Was there a hardware-level marker in the last sector, or an extra byte in the inter-sector space that wasn't "visible" by applications?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Excerpted from Inside Commodore DOS, page 53

**4.6  Sequential  File  Storage**

The format  of a sequential file is very straightforward.  All the sectors, except the last one, look like this:

TRACK LINK - SECTOR LINK - 254 BYTES OF DATA

```
 Byte   Purpose
 0      Track of the next block in this file
 1      Sector of the next block in this file
 2-255  254 bytes of data
```

The last block in a sequential file is special for two reasons:

1. It  is the  last  sector.
2. It  is  usually  only  partially full.

To signal the DOS that this is the last block, the first byte is set to $00. The first byte is normally the  track link.  Since there is no track 0, the  DOS knows that this is the last sector in the file. The second byte indicates the position of the last byte in the file.  Any bytes beyond this  position are garbage.

Comment: Oh, btw.  Here is a link to the book on the internet archive: https://ia800405.us.archive.org/19/items/Inside_Commodore_Dos/Inside_Commodore_Dos.pdf

Comment: That certainly makes sense. I had been wondering (mildly, in the background) about this for about 35 years... Thank you !